# How to run two synchronous process at same time in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Let two process function1, function2 are running at the same time.
function1// continuously appending the list
function2// take that the list from function1 and get all the data from the list and copy to another list, flush the original list and process that copied list.

```
sample code:


list_p =[]
def function1(data):
     list_p.append(data)

def function2(list_p):
      list_q = list_p.copy()
      list_p.flush()
      x= process(list_q)
      return x

while True:
    //coming data continously
    function1(coming data)
```

So, how to work with both function1 and function2 at a time so that I can get the data from function1 and flush it (after flushing start appending the index in function1 from 0) Also, at the same time list could be appending in function1.

At the same time, function1 could be appending the list and function 2 could be processing the new list, after finishing function2's process, It again takes all the data in the original list that was appending while function2 was processing.

continue..

Comment: Please read about Python GIL. Python is probably not the best language to do this task. If you have to use Python, maybe don't do it in threads, do it in loop or use persistent storage between functions.

Comment: You could use Queue class for it, it supports multithreading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html
You can also google for "Producer consumer problem"

Comment: If you don't use Queues ar any other synchronisation mechanism, then your code would always use 100% CPU, as function2 executes continiously even if list_p is empty. With Queues function 2 would be sleeping until there is really data to process.

As @Alex mentioned: performance wise multithreading with might not necessarily increase your performance, but this depends on where incoming data is coming from and what functions `process()` is calling.

Comment: here is an example with a Thread class: https://techmonger.github.io/55/producer-consumer-python/

Comment: @Alex Can you please explain or share any link related to "persistent storage between functions"?

Comment: @prabhuiitdhn persistent storage, meaning one function saves data to file or table, another function reads from there. Queue handlers should also work.

Comment: @marke, but until function2 finishes its execution function1 will in sleep mode according to the producer-consumers problem (If I am not wrong), In that case, function1 will lose some data while function2 will finish its execution. But I want function1 to continue so that I can't lose any data coming from input stream.

Comment: it would be a little bit easier to help with details of your problem. If threading is not good for you, you can look for producer consumer problem with multiprocessing or with some 3rd party libraries like Celery

Comment: @marke let's take a simple example:

I have two processes, P0, and P1; data is coming continuously from sensors(any sensor); I am just receiving the data from the sensor and sending it for fusion in process2 (in this case, fusion in process2 will take some time to pr) but at the same time data will be coming so, that continuos data I wanted to save until process2 finishes its execution so that I can process the saved data again.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you just need to read the data from the stream in one thread in a while loop, and process it in the other thread.

Comment: @marke yeah, you have understood it right. will you please write the sample code for it.?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `Threading`. In place of data stream I used `input` function in producer. (It's based on https://techmonger.github.io/55/producer-consumer-python/.)

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()
final_results = []

def producer():
    while True:
        i = int(input('Give me some number: '))  # here you should get data from data stream
        q.put(i)


def consumer():
    while True:
        number = q.get()
        result = number**2
        final_results.append(result)
        print(final_results)
        q.task_done()

t = Thread(target=consumer)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

producer()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @marke; This is really helpful. You saved my day :P